# Firebase - how to await getDownloadURL

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-storage

I have a function that retrieves the data from a document correctly. However, one image has the URL as it's field already. The other image only has a firebase image reference. Before I proceed to another function, I need to wait until the download URL has been fetched. I've attempted it below without much luck, and I'm not entirely sure i've stuck the `async` in the right place either.

```
getPhoto(user_id: string) {
   this._subscription = this._activatedRoute.params.pipe(
   switchMap(params => {
    return this.service.getPhoto(params);
  })
  ).subscribe(async(result) =>  {
    const imageOne = result.imageOne;

    // Need to await the download URL here
    const imageTwo = this.blah(result.imageTwoRef)

    this.otherFunction(imageOne, imageTwo)
  
  });
 }


blah(reference){
  var storage = firebase.storage();
  var imageTwo = reference;
  var imagePathRef = storage.ref().child(imageTwo);  
  imagePathRef.getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
    return url;
  }); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the async keyword only works on function, and by doing so, it will return a promise. So your usage is correct in that instance.
You can use await only in an async function and next to a promise call. It will stop the execution until your promise get resolved.
I think you are almost done. Try it like this and let me know:

```js
getPhoto(user_id: string) {
   this._subscription = this._activatedRoute.params.pipe(
   switchMap(params => {
    return this.service.getPhoto(params);
  })
  ).subscribe(async(result) =>  {
    const imageOne = result.imageOne;

    // Need to await the download URL here
    const imageTwo = await this.blah(result.imageTwoRef)

    this.otherFunction(imageOne, imageTwo);
  
  });
 }


async blah(reference){
  var storage = firebase.storage();
  var imageTwo = reference;
  var imagePathRef = storage.ref().child(imageTwo);  
  const url = await imagePathRef.getDownloadURL();
  return url;
}
```